# DataGrid bound to ReadOnly only editable on a new row object

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

When I add a new row to a DataGrid, hence creating a new object, only the new row is editable. Before I add a new row, the DataGrid is editable as it should be. I have set readonly to false inside the create method and notified the UI, but still, only the newly created line is editable. Does anyone have any ideas/suggestions on why this would be the case?

Thanks SO!

Comment: You state the DataGrid is editable as it should be and you also state only the new line is editable.  What is happening and what do you want?

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear, and why did you set readonly false, i hope this help you

```
public partial class Window2 
{
    public ObservableCollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        Foos = new ObservableCollection<Foo>(new List<Foo>
                                                 {
                                                     new Foo{ Column1 = "Some Data 1" , Column2 = "Some Data 1"},
                                                     new Foo{ Column1 = "Some Data 2" , Column2 = "Some Data 2"},
                                                 });
    }
}    
public class Foo
{
    public String Column1 { get; set; }
    public String Column2 { get; set; }

}
```

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Foos}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

you can check: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples